# $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{19} \sqrt{1+u_k^2} \rightarrow \min$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, dynamic-programming

> Solve $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{19} \sqrt{1+u_k^2} \rightarrow \min$, 
>   such that $x_0 = 0, x_{20} = 5$ and $x_{k+1} - x_k = u_k$.

---

I think I know how to solve problems like these recursively, but I don't know how I should attack this specific problem as it involves $20$ different $u_k$'s that need to be calculated (I think there must be a way to solve for general $u_k$ instead of recursively calculating each $u_k$). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This problem is equivalent to minimization of the distance between points $(0,0)$ and $(5,20)$ with the restriction that the path must go through $21$ point whose ordinates are $0,1,\ldots,20$. Clearly the optimal path is a straight line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! How did you figure out the points through which the line goes ($(5,20)$ seems to be the point that consits of the boundary conditions, but why?)? And how would I proceed to find all of the $u_k$'s?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{1+u_k^2}$ is a distance between $(x_k,k)$ and $(x_{k+1}, k+1)$, so the whole sum is the length of the polygonal chain which starts at $(x_0,0)=(0,0)$ and ends in $(x_{20},20)=(5,20)$. Additionally this ordinates of the points of the chain must be all the integers from $\{0,\ldots,20\}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: How could you see so quickly that $\sqrt{1+u_k^2}$ is the distance between $(x_k,k)$ and $(x_{k+1},k+1)$? And how do you know that all the points of the chain must be integers?

Comment: @user105842 Becasue the square root of the sum of two squares often hints to distance between certain points

Comment: @Norbert I think this is not an appropriate explanation Norbert... Can you please be more specific for them

Comment: @Norbert I understand that, but how do you know it is the distance between $(x_k,k)$ and $(x_{k+1},k+1)$? And why are the points of the chain integers?

Comment: @user105842 $$\sqrt{1+u_k^2}=\sqrt{((k+1) - k)^2+(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2}=\\=\mbox{the distance between }(x_k,k)\mbox{ and }(x_{k+1},k+1)$$ As for the second question, I just noticed that we need to form a chain to give a reasonable interpretation of the that sum of roots, i. e. an interpretation as the sum of length of segments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to solve this problem.

First, we make the observation that
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sqrt{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}^3} > 0$$
This implies the function $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is a strictly convex function for $x$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Second, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{19} u_k = \sum_{k=0}^{19}(x_{k+1} - x_{k}) = x_{20} - x_0 = 5$$

Using [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), we obtain:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{19}\sqrt{1+u_k^2} \ge 20 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{20}\sum_{k=0}^{19}u_k\right)^2}
= 20 \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4^2}} = 5\sqrt{17}
$$
It is clear above equality can be achieved when all $u_k$ is the same, i.e. equal to $\frac{5}{20} = \frac14$. This means the desired minimum is $5\sqrt{17}$.